# EMIT Select Option in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

My PHP code is returning a list of users out of a MySQL database and putting them in a select list using a JQuery combo box each of them in their own  field. There are a couple names out of the DB that need to stay in the DB but don't really need to be in the drop down list as selectable names... is there a way to emit options in my code before the MySQL Query even runs? Or what is the best way to handle this?

Here is my current code:

```
// Write out our query.
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT FULLNAME FROM cimssystem.cimsusers ORDER BY FULLNAME;";

// Execute it, or let it throw an error message if there's a problem.
$stmt = $pdo->query( $query );

$datalist = "<select id='name-select' name='name'>";

$datalist .= "\n<option value='0' selected></option>";

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $datalist .= "\n<option value='{$row['FULLNAME']}'>{$row['FULLNAME']}</option>";
}

$datalist .= "\n</select>";

echo $datalist;

?>
```

Comment: "but don't really need to be in the drop down list as selectable names..." Why not select just the names you need in "combo box"?

Comment: I need all names (50+) except for about 5 and the names I do need in might change over time.

Comment: I suppose there must be some logic to distinct needed names from the ones that need to be hidden, and it should be implemented in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities here, but this is one example:
`$query = "SELECT DISTINCT FULLNAME FROM cimssystem.cimsusers WHERE FULLNAME NOT IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3') ORDER BY FULLNAME;";`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to do it in the SQL... I got so caught up in the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are capable of modifying the database, you can add an 'Enabled' column and set the values to true/false accordingly for each entry. You can then simply modify the query to add a check for that column's values. I find this easier than modifying the query to exclude a specific list of people, and it reduces the possibility of a typo on my end in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I was so caught up in my code I didn't think about going back and selecting them in the database! Just have to make sure to move the order by to the end of the statement for this to work correctly!

```
SELECT DISTINCT FULLNAME FROM cimssystem.cimsusers 
WHERE FULLNAME NOT IN ('Berryville CSR Intern', 'name', 'name')
ORDER BY FULLNAME ;
```